# Get program name for PID using PHP

Tags: php, linux

I am attempting to do something that is a little risky. Its a private script, but i want to add some security so I don't accidentally enter an invalid PID.

Currently if a script hangs it will lock up the port it uses, i need to kill the PID and then restart it. I want to add a new argument to this script so i can pass in the old PID and the script will kill that PID before starting again. Using `netstat -tulpen` i see that there is a program name tied to a PID. I want to make sure that the program name is PHP so i dont shut down a different process by accident. E.g. check that PID 15498 was created by PHP (15498/php)

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1067            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          201425     15498/php
```

I had a look on the file system and i found a directory for the PID, but all of the files within this directory are empty. `/proc/15498`

Once i can validate that this is a relatively safe PID to kill i can then run the command to kill it.

```
exec("kill -SIGKILL 15498");
```

Comment: Did you try reading `/proc/15498/cmdline`?

Comment: Ignore the fact that `ls` says the files have zero length. They're not real files, when you read them they pull the information out of the kernel.

Comment: Ah this is even better, it tells me the php script it originated from too. This will do perfectly. Is there a safe way to parse this data? It seems to be delimited by something that is showing up as "NUL" when i view it in notepad++

Comment: It's a C-style string, so it ends with a `\0` character. You can simply remove it with `trim()` or `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the command line from `/proc/PID/cmdline`, and remove the trailing null byte.

```
$cmd = trim(file_get_contents("/proc/$pid/cmdline"), "\0");
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to check for process with arguments use this:

```
$cmd = str_replace("\0", " ", trim(file_get_contents("/proc/$pid/cmdline"), "\0"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the system php call and pass it the shell command to look up process information which then you can pipe through grep with the PID to look up the process name